# Why does the onclick event not work, in my razor pages hosted blazor component, in .net 7.0?

Tags: razor-pages, blazor-webassembly, .net-7.0

This code has been working just right in a blazor web assembly, embedded in a razor pages page, using .net 5.0 and .net 6.0.
I had to upgrade to .net 7.0, by altering the framework in razor pages and blazor projects' properties, to fix a big something else and now it doesn't work.
The onclick event is just not being detected.

```
<p>@(Myawesomevariable)</p>

<button @onclick="Myawesomefunction">Myawesomebutton</button>

@code
{
    private int Myawesomevariable = 0;

    private void Myawesomefunction()
    {
        Myawesomevariable++;
    }
}
```

What th' flip?

Comment: Whoever voted to close this question hasn't done their homework.
The problem is real and specific to .net 7.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, you lucky people, here's the fix.

In .net 7.0, first create blazor webassembly solution from the visual studio template, with a client, a server and a shared project.

From the client project, `wwwroot` folder, delete the `index.html` file.

From the client project, delete these two lines in the `program.cs` file:

```
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");
```

Create a new blazor server project using the visual studio template and copy the `_Host.cshtml` file from the blazor server project's `pages` folder, to your project's `pages` folder and remove the following lines:

```
<link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="<THE PROJECT NAMESPACE>.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

and

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

Replacing them with:

```
<link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="<YOUR PROJECT NAMESPACE>.Client.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered" />
```

and

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
```

Create a new razor pages project and copy the following files from the razor pages `pages` folder to your projects `pages` folder:

```
Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml
Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml.css
Pages/_ViewImports.cshtml
Pages/_ViewStart.cshtml
```

In the imported `_Host.cshtml` file, edit the namespace to

```
@namespace <YOUR PROJECT NAMESPACE>.Server.Pages
```

and add a reference to the client project

```
@using <YOUR PROJECT NAMESPACE>.Client
```

Finally, remove any references to `blazor.server.js` and make sure every blazor pages calls the `blazor.webassembly.js file`.

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

I now have a .net 7.0 razor pages project, with blazor components embedded in different pages AND the onclick event handler works.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the most recent example from the visual studio 2022 template's counter.Razor you can see a `@rendermode InteractiveServer` line. Adding that got mine working :)

At least for .net 8.